# Adding Background image to Firebase SignIn Screen in xCode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, authentication

Currently I bought a source code for a social media app that uses firebase for the sign up/ log in page, but I'm seeing that log in page has no background image and sign up buttons are at the bottom leaving a blank screen on the entire page.

I'm a noobi when it comes to coding in xCode so hope you can help me with adding a background image.

So currently I have 2 files that control the Auth screen (Authclient.swift & WelcomeViewController.swift)

I've been going through the files and looks like "WelcomeViewController.swift" controls the sign in screen... This is the code I have in that file:

```
import UIKit

import SwiftHEXColors

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAuthUI

import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI
import FirebaseTwitterAuthUI
import FirebasePhoneAuthUI

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var progressView:UIView? // view shown while data is loading
@IBOutlet weak var welcomeView:UIView? // view when data is loaded. like sign-in or intro

var client:AuthClient?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.welcomeView?.isHidden = true
    self.progressView?.isHidden = false

    let config = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    #if DEBUG
        config.configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
    #endif

    config.fetch(withExpirationDuration: 100) { (status, error) -> Void in
        if status == .success {
            print("Config fetched!")
            config.activateFetched()
        } else {
            print("Config not fetched")
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error available.")")
        }

        self.defineTheme(config)
        self.welcomeView?.isHidden = false
        self.progressView?.isHidden = true

        // if user authorized, go to main page
        if (Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "auth.mute", sender: nil)
        } else {
            self.buttonPressed(self)
        }
    }
}

// FIRAuthUIDelegate

func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
    if let errorHandler = error as NSError? {
        self.showError(errorHandler.localizedDescription)
        // print user-info. find more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors
        print(errorHandler.userInfo)
    } else {
        if let currentUser = user {

            // update displayname and photo
            let name = currentUser.displayName ?? kDefaultUsername
            let photo = currentUser.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? kDefaultProfilePhoto

            client?.saveUser(userId: currentUser.uid,
                                         name: name,
                                         photo: photo,
                                         override: false)
//user?.sendEmailVerification(completion: nil)
        }

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "auth", sender: nil)
    }
}

// Helpers

func showError(_ error:String) {
    print("Error: \(error)")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: kAlertErrorTitle, message: error, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: kAlertErrorDefaultButton, style: .default) { (action) in })
    self.present(alert, animated: true) {}
}

func defineTheme(_ config:RemoteConfig) {
    var primary = UIColor.white
    var secondary = UIColor.blue

    if let string = config[kPrimaryColor].stringValue, !string.isEmpty {
        primary = UIColor(hexString: string)!
    }

    if let string = config[kSecondaryColor].stringValue, !string.isEmpty {
        secondary = UIColor(hexString: string)!
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = primary
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = secondary
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
        [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:secondary], for: UIControlState.normal)

    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = primary
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = secondary

    UIButton.appearance().tintColor = secondary
}

// Actions
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    authUI?.delegate = self

    /* 
     * Uncommend this lines to add Google and Facebook authorization. But first 
     * enabled it in Firebase Console. More information you can find here:
     * https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin
     * https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login
     */
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
//            FUIGoogleAuth(),
//            FUIFacebookAuth(),
//            FUITwitterAuth(),
        FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:authUI!),
        ]
    authUI?.providers = providers
    /* 
     kEulaUrl needs to be set in Config.swift file. required for publishing
     */
    authUI?.tosurl = URL(string:kEulaUrl)

    if (Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "auth.mute", sender: nil)
    } else {
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()

        self.present(authViewController, animated: true) {
            // ..
        }
    }
}

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to add a background image to this screen. Already have my 3 images in Assets.xcassets named bgLogin.imageset.

Thanks

Comment: I only had this answer in such detail because I had the same problem and scoured the project looking for the right place to edit the code. After a while I uncovered a tool called **Debug View Hierarchy** that is in the Debug Area. Inside of there I was able to look at each view that laid out and then backtrack it to the file that controlled the views and extend it.

Comment: Awesome sauce! Thanks Jake.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want to do.

Create an extension of their baseViewController

```
 extension FUIAuthBaseViewController {
```

Inside of that extension, override their `viewWillAppear()` and set the image there

```
open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    // if view is base view add logo as subview
    let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first
    if vc == self.navigationController?.visibleViewController {
        makeLogoImage()
    } else {
        // hide the image in proceeding views by covering it with a white background
        vc?.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}


/**
 Create imageView and display it at the top of the screen.
 */
func makeLogoImage() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "angel.png"))
    let width = view.frame.width
    let height = view.frame.height
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: width / 4, y: height / 8 , width: width / 2, height: width / 2)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
}
```

Comment: All of this is done in the same file "WelcomeViewController.swift" right?

Comment: No. this should all be placed in it's own file

Comment: No luck, got error:  Cannot convert return expression of type '[ArraySlice<TimePeriodProtocol>]' to return type '[AnySequence<TimePeriodProtocol>]'

Comment: I believe that is an unrelated error. Do you know where the application returns that error?

Comment: At TimePeriodGroup.swift” which is locked for editing, dunno if by xCode or original developer.

Comment: Got it! Will keep trying. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running the XCode 9.3 Beta?

Comment: If not. Do you have it installed? That may be the source of that error. You may need to update your pods or uninstall the 9.3 beta

Comment: You know just this morning when I opened xCode it started updating and checking it now I do have xCode 9.3

Comment: Try running `pod update` in your terminal open at that folder and see if that fixes it

Comment: Ok got it working half way, where as the image shows but on top of everything, including buttons. Also had to downgrade xCode to 9.2

Comment: try adding `self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)` to the end of `makeLogoImage()` I happen to have 9.3 now too and it's taking forever to index my project I had that code in.

Comment: Thanks Jake.
Will definitely use your answer, just needed to add at the very end of your code these two lines:

`self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)`

And that got image to go behind the buttons :)

Comment: That works too! If this resolved your issue go ahead and mark that this was the solution.

Comment: Jake how can I send you a private message?

Comment: I don't know I've never initiated it. But I think that if there are a lot of comments like this then there is a link that appears near the "show more comments"

Comment: After looking you can Chat when you have [20 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: Updated the answer to prevent the image from deleting but still being hidden from the proceeding views.